# phpMyAdmin - Error Mysql error during session start

Tags: php, mysql, session, phpmyadmin

I had a problem with MySQL, this problem appears after I clean chrome browsing data.

The error looks like this.
[image]

This error appears every time I access PHPMyAdmin, and also I can't access my databases.

What I already did so far are :

1. https://github.com/rtCamp/easyengine/issues/302 - not work
2. Access PHPMyAdmin from other browsers -same result

Prepare for the worst, how to back up my databases?, because I can't access my databases from terminal.

UPDATE :
I have been following this [link](https://wiki.phpmyadmin.net/pma/session.save_path) and create `php_error.php` file this is the result

> Warning: session_start(): open(/opt/lampp/temp//sess_eobqtotm38tean46jjthbih1m3, O_RDWR) failed:
>   Permission denied (13) in /opt/lampp/htdocs/portofolio1/php_error.php
>   on line 6
>
> If a session could be started successfully you should not see any
>   Warning(s), otherwise check the path/folder mentioned in the
>   warning(s) for proper access rights. The current "session.save_path"
>   is "/opt/lampp/temp/". Session file name:
>   "sess_eobqtotm38tean46jjthbih1m3".
>
> Warning: Unknown:
>   open(/opt/lampp/temp//sess_eobqtotm38tean46jjthbih1m3, O_RDWR) failed:
>   Permission denied (13) in Unknown on line 0
>
> Warning: Unknown: Failed to write session data (files). Please verify
>   that the current setting of session.save_path is correct
>   (/opt/lampp/temp/) in Unknown on line 0

Now what I should do next?

> SOLVED!

[Follow this web](https://azuraakbar.wordpress.com/2012/05/30/52/)

By typing this on terminal

```
sudo chmod -R 705 /opt/lampp/temp/sess_su8nntc1mvi9t3t6b3vu67kuquc9p012
```

and

```
sudo chown -R $user /opt/lampp/temp/sess_su8nntc1mvi9t3t6b3vu67kuquc9p012

change $user with your username

sess_su8nntc1mvi9t3t6b3vu67kuquc9p012 is my session file, it should be different on your system
```

Thanks, axiac^^

Comment: I suppose doing what the error message suggested and **looking in your PHP error log and/or the Apache error log**  was the next thing you were going to do then!!!

Comment: It says it quite clearly: **"check the path/folder mentioned in the warning(s) for proper access rights. The current ''session.save_path'' is ''/opt/lampp/temp/''"**. The web server is not allowed to create files in that directory. Fix the permissions (or better, the owner of that directory as it seems to be dedicated for `lamp`) and it will work.

Comment: @stacheldraht27 Would you mind answering your own question and accepting it instead of including your answer in the question body? It's more readable that way

Answer (score -1):

Try like this

```
sudo chown root:root /opt/lampp/temp/sess_243ca2147169ded5d73ae8290b2f68fe
```