# Phpmyadmin not functioning in xampp

Tags: php, xampp, ubuntu-18.04, apache2.2

> Error during session start; please check your PHP and/or webserver log file and configure your PHP installation properly. Also ensure that cookies are enabled in your browser.
>
> session_start(): open(SESSION_FILE, O_RDWR) failed: Permission denied (13)
>
> session_start(): Failed to read session data: files (path: /opt/lampp/temp/)

Things tried:
Changing file permissions and ownership.
Removing cookies from browser
Different browser

Things to note:
using ubuntu 18
mssql installed
uninstalled mysql previously and reinstalled again
mysql save installation also done

Comment: Did you check the error log?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28582967/phpmyadmin-error-mysql-error-during-session-start Is this not similar to your question? The OP answered in the question body